# Сделать одинаковую высоту блоков

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать одинаковую высоту блоков, при чем не фиксированную, а чтобы можно было добавлять контент и высота всего блока menu подстраивалась под больший из двух блоков (products и category).

Не использовать flexbox, нужна как можно бОльшая поддержка браузеров

```css
.products,
.category {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.products {
  background: #ccc;
}

.category {
  background: #398;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="products">
    <li>
      item
    </li>
    <li>
      item
    </li>
    <li>
      item
    </li>
    <li>
      item
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="category">
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').css({
    height: $('.menu').height()
  })
});
```

```css
.products,
.category {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.products {
  background: #ccc;
}

.category {
  background: #398;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="products">
    <li>
      item
    </li>
    <li>
      item
    </li>
    <li>
      item
    </li>
    <li>
      item
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="category">
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>cat</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавить _больший из двух блоков_

Comment: @DiDex, больший список будет растягивать блок .menu. Таким образом все будет работать. Высота списка равна 100% от родителя. Мы не знаем точно какая высота будет у меню, поэтому вычисляем ее после рендеринга.

Comment: зачем для такого jQuery ? это же основы css ...

Comment: Интересно. Вот пришла идея сделать такое условие:
если высота блока "products" равна определенному числу, то у блока "category" сделать min-height со значением высоты "products".  Не будет ли это костылём?))

Comment: @StepanIvanov  вы хотите сделать высоту меню на js ? вообще использование js для этого костыль жОсткий костыль

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Да скорее всего. Вот насколько я понял на сайте https://www.dns-shop.ru/ имеено используется js (второе выпадающее меню - на скрине "ноутбуки и аксессуары")
http://prntscr.com/jlfjkf

Comment: @StepanIvanov  ты такое меню делаешь ? в таком меню другой  механизм

Comment: @МаксимЛенский да пытаюсь сделать такое, а блоки я привел в пример, как одна из частей этого меню т.е один блок категорий, а другой уже подкатегории, у которых должна быть одинаковая высота. Если что не так - пиши, подкорректирую вопрос

Comment: @StepanIvanov  ни чего корректировать не надо ..и так ясно что не верный ассоциацию придумали ... там вообще всё по другому

Comment: @StepanIvanov  я дополнил ответ .... вторым вариантом именно такое выпадающее меню без jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Старый добрый `table-cell` даже калькуляторы поддерживают

высота родителя сама подстраивается под высоту большего потомка

по БЭМ

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item__menu {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.item__menu--link {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1000px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

@media (max-width:865px) {
  .item__menu--link {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Georgia;
  }
}

@media (min-width:865px) {
  .item__menu--link {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item__menu">
    <a href="#" class="item__menu--link">пункт меню</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item__menu">
    <a href="#" class="item__menu--link">второй пункт меню</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item__menu">
    <a href="#" class="item__menu--link">третий пункт с ещё одним словом</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item__menu">
    <a href="#" class="item__menu--link">этот пункт длинее прошлого но все они будут вертикалится</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item__menu">
    <a href="#" class="item__menu--link">котроткий пункт меню</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

меню из вашего комментария

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  padding: 6px 40px 4px 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

ul li:hover {
  border-right: none;
}

ul li .hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: none;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>texttext1</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext2</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext3</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext4</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext5</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem5</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext6</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem6</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext7</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem7</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext8</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem8</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext9</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem9</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext10</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem10</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext11</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem11</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext12</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem12</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext13</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem13</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext14</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem14</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext15</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem15</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext16</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem16</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext17</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem17</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext18</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem18</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext19</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem19</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>texttext20</span>
    <div class="hidden">text elem20</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```